# Pointwise multiplication of two incidence matrices

Tags: graph-theory

Does pointwise multiplication of two incidence matrices of respective graphs represent something in terms of graphs?

Comment: The incidence matrix being a 0-1 matrix, the pointwise (or [Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices))) product acts as an AND operator. Therefore it identifies the intersection of these graphs (i.e. edges that appear in both).